# notifyDataSetChanged() not showing up for custom list adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

[image: link]
I have a custom array adapter than extends ArrayAdapter, but the notifyDataSetChanged() method just plain doesn't show up(and does not work if you try it).

```
class matchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Match> {
public matchAdapter(Context context, List<Match> matches) {
    super(context, R.layout.match_layout, matches);
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The above is from my adapter class. Would notifyAll() do the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly your answer, but some comments: **1)** why do you need to override the method if you're not doing anything at all with it? **2)** Java guidelines recommend that you name your classes in camel case, always starting with capital letters. **3)** Add the `public` modifier to your `MatchAdapter` class.

Comment: is the `listAdapter` a reference of `matchAdapter ` or a reference of its superclass

Comment: @PauloAvelar 1) I just overrided it just to make sure that the method itself was there, I took it out afterwards. 2) I'll keep that in mind, thanks! 3) Done, but still nothing new.

Comment: @Jerome It's a reference of matchAdapter class

Comment: I see. That might be an IDE issue. One more try, what about cleaning your project using **Build > Clean Project**?

Comment: @PauloAvelar Tried that as well, to no avail

Comment: Okay, I won't make this a chat (against the rules), but that's getting interesting. If I have any ideas, I'll post them as an answer.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was trying to use it to refresh a ListView. I switched to using `listView.invalidateViews()`. It's really not a great solution but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `listAdapter` is declared as having the type `ListAdapter`, which doesn't have the method you expect (`notifyDataSetChanged`). You need to make it at least `BaseAdapter` or cast it to a `BaseAdapter`(I am assuming your `MatchAdapter` is at least a `BaseAdapter` - if not, well, calling such a method would make no sense:-) )

```
((BaseAdapter)listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll write an example, it's not a real code but it's how you have to do this.

1. Create your `List`

   `ArrayList<matchList> matchList = new ArrayList<matchList>();`
2. Create an `Adapter`

   `adapter = new matchAdapter(this, matchList);`
3. Set the `Adapter`

   `YourListView.setAdapter(adapter);`
4. You change the stuff on your `List`

   `matchList.add(Stuff for your list);`
5. Notify now that `List` has changed doing :

   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Hope it helps to you, if it does not, just type a comment and I'll try to update my answer.

### Edit

I'll give you some examples...

When you want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` just do this :

```
List.clear();
List.addAll(YourStuff);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Other method could be, you are using an `AsyncTask` so your `onBackGround()` you could make it returns items for your list, then on your `onPostExecute` update the adapter.

Example :

```
 @Override
  protected List<matchList> doInBackground(String... params) {
       List<matchList> items = loadUpdatedDataset(params);
       return items;
  }      

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<matchList> itemschangeds) {
    updateAdapterDataset(itemschangeds);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did all of that. matchList is populated before the adapter is called for the first time, so what I have is.
 

    listAdapter = new matchAdapter(MainActivity.this, matchList);
            matchHistory.setAdapter(listAdapter);  

But I still can't get the notifyDataSetChanged method to show up for my adapter.

Comment: Do you have all as a Global variables?

Comment: Yeah sure, but you call `clear()`, `add()`, `insert()` or `remove()` after try to call `notifydatasetchanged()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by global, but the matchList and adapter are declared in the class, not within a method. All of this happens within the same class

Comment: Make a Clear project or rebuild it again

Comment: @robertle Can you just paste all of your code? where you use your list adapter, etc?....

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) { //intents to activity showing the user's match history
            listAdapter = new matchAdapter(MainActivity.this, matchList);
            matchHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.matchHistoryList);
          
            matchHistory.setAdapter(listAdapter); //sets the array adapter to the match history list view
            matchHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { //detects on click on a specific item

         

        
        } `
This is within an asynctask class. Oh god how do I format

Comment: Where do you want to notify?

Comment: I call the asynctask every time a user searches for a "summoner," so it could be right after all of that. Don't know why it's not showing up though

Comment: So where you are adding content?

Comment: It happens in the doInBackground() method of the asynctask

Comment: So, each time you clear add etc.. you call `listview.setAdapter(adapter)`?

Comment: Yes. I know setting the adapter over and over isn't necessary, but it never caused any issues so I didn't end up moving it

Comment: And in your `onPostExecute()` have you tried something like `listAdapter.this.notifydatasetchanged()`?

Comment: Tried both of those, but notifyDataSetChanged() still does not appear as an option for my adapter.

Comment: It's fine, I can find a workaround for my problem for now. Thanks for bearing with me though^^

Comment: If you want I can create a chat room and I keep helping you until get with the issue :)

Comment: That'd be cool but I'm about to go for the night. If you're still willing to help tomorrow, I'm up for it

Comment: @robertle Up to you :) but if I see you code it will be fast.

Comment: Create the room, I'll send you the stuff

Comment: Let me know wheb you are able its 4:37 am here and my body needs to rest, tomorrow we'll solve de issue!

Comment: Give me 30 min please

Comment: @robertle I've created the room just past all the code on it :) [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88192/notifydatasetchange-issue)

Comment: looks like i don't have enough rep to chat :/

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/36yTwAHDCgGev7mxFr4a9Tt  
and http://paste.ofcode.org/VW3xJvJse25LsTxRtDLrrS

Comment: Could you try the onbackground and onpostexecute that i gave to you? I mean yout doinbackground return a list and then on your post get that list

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/enBfuwbgrZmcNATvnKWFiH. Still, neither updateAdapterDataSet or notifyDataSetChanged show up as valid methods

Comment: But you have to put `listAdapter = new MatchAdapter(MainActivity.this, changedmatchlist);`

Comment: Like you had the code on start it shows something? or it gives to you some error? The problem is that you can't see the List updated, right?

Comment: Take a look on [this example](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2014/03/29/how-to-refresh-listview-arrayadapter-in-asynctask/)

Comment: The problem is mainly I can't use notifyDataSetChanged. For the asynctask itself, it kind of works through my workaround by setting the adapter to the listview again every single time a user is searched, but it has somewhat of a glitchy behaviour and I don't think it's proper programming. I just feel like notifyDataSetChanged would be very useful

Comment: Have you tried using my AsyncTask example for example on your `onPostExecute()` make a clear from matchList, and then matchList.addAll(changedmatchlist); then try to put adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Also, I don't know but you can try it, you can set the adapter on your onBackground too, and then you update the adapter on your onPostExecute?

Comment: Also, I've read on SO answers, that you can do a runonuithread in your on PostExecute so you can try : runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

     this.adapter.setList(list);
     this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

});

Comment: Hey @robertle how's going? Have you solved your question? :D

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply, I've just gone ahead and kept what I had originally, appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling and running the app? If there are any syntax errors above your `matchAdapter` (like a missing ; or "), it'll screw the autocompletion up.

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents.. has he tried manually typing `notifyDataSetChanged()`? If that doesn't work, it might be a corrupt sdk file

Comment: Try replacing `matchAdapter()` with `ArrayAdapter<Match>()`, then see if notifyDataSetChanged shows up

Comment: Weird. Can you upload your project to github? I'll try it in my environment and see what happens